# Sentences with "no one"

Tags: prepositions, objects

Is there at least one right sentence on the list?

1) You should **say it to no one**

2) You should**n't say it to no one**

3) You say it **to no one**

Comment: 2. You shouldn't say it to anyone.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like there're no right sentences? aren't it? And the way that you conveyed is the only way. I know that easiest way to say this sentence is above mentioned but I wanted to find some different from regular way to say it in order to diversify and emphasize it in some way if it possible and correct in terms of grammar

Comment: Sentence 1 is good and sentence 3 is ok but would be better as 'You tell no one'

Comment: _It seems like there're no right sentences? aren't it?_ Max, you should put questions like that **in  your question**, not in the comments down below your question. Right now, Chris M has answered your question, and there's nothing left to say on the matter.

Comment: Both #1 and #3 are grammatically correct, but they mean different things.  It's very hard to tell you which one is "right" if you don't tell us what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes! Your first and third statements are grammatically correct.**

- **No one** - means *nobody*, can also be written as *no-one*.

> So your first sentence means: *You should say it to nobody.*

As it is constructed it may convey any different emotional part of **politeness**, **advice** or **a hint**.

> The second sentence sounds more like an **order** or a **command**. It implies more rudeness.

On the other hand as **Chris M** advised the better option might be:

- *You shouldn't say it to anyone.*

Depending on your emotional choice the right formulation might differ.

Your third sentence: *You shouldn't say it to no one.*

That is a double negative which certainly implies an opposite meaning:

- *You should say it to anyone.*

> Double negatives are to be avoided in English and are counted to be
>   grammatically incorrect though I personally often times ignore this
>   myself and find some examples of using double negatives absolutely and
>   logically correct. But this is my personal point of view.

Comment: @Max Wait for more answers. Somebody might give a better explanation. Somebody might disagree with me.

Comment: Maybe you right, on the other hand, the crucial point of your answer matches other's explanations

Comment: **about double negatives** [link](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/03/7-grammar-myths-you-learned-in-school/)